# python sum tuple list based on tuple first value

Tags: python, list, sum

Suppose I have the following list tuples:

```
myList = [(0,2),(1,3),(2,4),(0,5),(1,6)]
```

I want to sum this list based on the same first tuple value:

```
[(n,m),(n,k),(m,l),(m,z)] = m*k + l*z
```

For `myList`

```
sum = 2*5 + 3*6 = 28
```

How can I got this?

Comment: Your question isn't particularly clear on how the output should be calculated...

Comment: Why nothing happes with (2,4) element? And what do you want to happen if the first tuple value appears 3 or more times?

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. For those tuples, if they have the same first field, multiply their second field. Ignore tuples having no same first field. At last sum mutiple values.

Comment: @stephenlee Don't worry your English was fine and so was your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from operator import mul
>>> lis = [(0,2),(1,3),(2,4),(0,5),(1,6)]
>>> dic = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k,v in lis:
    dic[k].append(v)  #use the first item of the tuple as key and append second one to it
...     

#now multiply only those lists which contain more than 1 item and finally sum them.
>>> sum(reduce(mul,v) for k,v in dic.items() if len(v)>1)
 28
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

def mul(args): # will work with more than 2 arguments, e.g. 2*3*4
    return reduce(lambda acc, x: acc*x, args, 1)

myList = [(0,2),(1,3),(2,4),(0,5),(1,6)]
sorted_ = sorted(myList, key=itemgetter(0))
grouped = groupby(sorted_, key=itemgetter(0))
numbers = [[t[1] for t in items] for _, items in grouped]
muls = [mul(items) for items in numbers if len(items) > 1]
print sum(muls)
```

Comment: from `groupby` docs: "Generally, the iterable needs to already be sorted on the same key function"

Comment: Ok, now I get your comment. Agree. Instead of "no need of sorting here", it should be "no need of sorting and groupby here" :)

Comment: @JakubM. He means that there is a more efficient way to do it

Answer (score 0):

This solution does it in a single pass as opposed to the more readable `defaultdict` version which takes two passes and may take more space:

```
myList = [(0,2),(1,3),(2,4),(0,5),(1,6)]
sum_ = 0
once, twice = {}, {}
for x, y in myList:
    if x in once:
        sum_ -= twice.get(x, 0)
        twice[x] = twice.get(x, once[x]) * y
        sum_ += twice[x]
    else:
        once[x] = y


>>> sum_
28
```

Answer (score 0):

With below program even if you have multiple entries and not only two for same key, it will work

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

myList = [(0,2),(1,3),(2,4),(0,5),(1,6),(1,2)]

h = {}
c = {}
sum = 0

for k in myList:
        # if key value already present
        if k[0] in c:
                if k[0] in h:
                        sum = sum - h[k[0]]
                        h[k[0]] = h[k[0]] * k[1]
                else:
                        h[k[0]] = c[k[0]] * k[1]
                sum = sum + h[k[0]]
        else:
                # stores key and value if first time though the loop
                c[k[0]] = k[1]                
print('sum is' + str(sum))
```