# Sum up the third value for conditions

Tags: python

I want to write a quick calculation in python, not sure how to approach this:

```
values = [(0, 4, .3), (6, 2, 3), (3, 7, 2.2), (5, 5, .5), (3, 5, .8), (7, 7, .3)]
```

say we use (x, y, z) to represent tuples in values

```
criteria = [(a, b, c, d)]
```

if (a <= x < b) and (c <= y < d), 
then sum up all the z in the values.

My result is just to show the sum of z that satisfy the above criteria

Comment: If `value` is one of the tuples in `values` (e.g. `value = (0, 4, .3)`), do you know how to check whether it satisfies the criteria?

Comment: first show your code.

Comment: sample input, sample outpu ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/28706209/2988730

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension to achieve that in one line.

```
# Criteria
(a, b, c, d) = (-1, 10, 0, 10)

# Output
zs = [z for (x, y, z) in values if a <= x < b and c <= y < d]
print(sum(zs))
```

Not fully sure why you specified the `criteria` as an array, but I think that example is easy to extend in case you want to check for multiple criterias.